# How do I conditionally make warnings fatal?

Tags: perl

I want to have fatal errors that can be demoted to warnings (or conversely, warnings that can be promoted to fatal errors) depending on the user's preference. At present, I'm using `die` and overriding it like this:

```
my $force;
BEGIN {
    no warnings 'once';
    Getopt::Long::Configure('pass_through');
    GetOptions('force', \$force);
    *CORE::GLOBAL::die = sub { warn @_ } if $force;
    Getopt::Long::Configure('no_pass_through');
}

use My::Module;
...
die "maybe";
...
exit(1) if $force;
exit(0); # success!
```

I don't like this approach, mostly because there are a few places where I still want to die (e.g. missing command-line arguments). I'd rather change (most) instances of `die` to `warn` and do a conditional `use warnings FATAL => 'all'`<sup>1</sup>. The problem is that `use warnings` is lexically scoped, so this is ineffective:

```
if (!$force) {
    use warnings FATAL => 'all';
}
```

Attempting to use a postfix conditional is a syntax error:

```
use warnings FATAL => 'all' unless $force;
```

and `use` can't be used in an expression:

```
$force or use warnings FATAL => 'all';  # syntax error
```

I can think of various distasteful work-arounds (Defining my own warn/die, duplicating my main script code in an if/else, etc.) but am seeking an elegant solution that conditionally applies `use warnings` in the current lexical scope. (Applying it in the parent scope would work as well but would likely require dark magic.)

---

<sub>1: Actually, I want to add `use warnings::register` to my modules and `use warnings FATAL => 'My::Module'` to my script, but the distinction is unimportant for the purposes of this question.</sub>

Comment: Bit of a learning curve but, have you seen [Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
use if !$force, warnings => qw( FATAL all );
```

Yes, there's a module called `if` that is distributed with Perl to make it really easy to do conditional imports.

Note that this is evaluated at **compile time**, so `$force` needs to be defined at compile time. (Probably within a `BEGIN { ... }` block.) Based on the code samples in your question, you seem to have figured that part out already though.

Alternatively, more manual:

```
BEGIN {
    require warnings;
    warnings->import(qw/ FATAL all /) unless $force;
}
```

A completely different approach would be to use a signal handler `$SIG{__WARN__}` or `$SIG{__DIE__}` to decide to die or not at run-time.