# How to make numeric warning fatal?

Tags: perl

I am not able to make the numeric warning fatal:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my  $y = "a";
if ($y > 0) {
    say "Should not happen";
}
say "P1";
{
    say "y = $y";
    use warnings FATAL => qw(numeric);
    if ($y > 0) {
        say "Should not happen";
    }
}
say "Done";
```

Output is:

```
Argument "a" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at p.pl line 6.
P1
y = a
Done
```

Expected output:

```
Argument "a" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at p.pl line 6.
P1
y = a
Argument "a" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at p.pl line 13.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you only get the warning the first time you do this with a variable, has nothing to do with `FATAL`

Comment: One heavy handed way to force it to be fatal is by setting the warn signal handler, `$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { die $_[0]; };` as an answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539975/how-do-i-conditionally-make-warnings-fatal) suggests. But I know you only want numerical warnings to be fatal so this probably not what you want(and manually filtering `$_[0]` in  the handler seems clumsy).

Comment: @Dmitry Nope, there's no no warning, so that won't trigger

Comment: @ikegami I probably misunderstand what fatal means in the context of Perl. I was convinced it meant to halt execution on first instance of the warning/warn using `die`.

Comment: @Dmitry. It does. But there's no warning. It's not just not dying, it's also not warning. See my answer for why.

Comment: @ikegami You're right, I misunderstood the problem. I didn't realize OP wanted only the second warning to fail not the first one. Furthermore, My `$SIG` suggestion does not work(neither warns nor dies) if installed after the first warning because of the caching behavior you mention in your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you convert a variable to numeric, that conversion is cached. This means that `$y` *is* numeric after the first `$y > 0`, so the second neither warns nor dies.

Modified test:

```perl
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my  $y = my $z = "a";
if ($y > 0) {
    say "Should not happen";
}
say "P1";
{
    use warnings FATAL => qw(numeric);
    if ($z > 0) {
        say "Should not happen";
    }
}
say "Done";
```

Output:

```
Argument "a" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at a.pl line 6.
P1
Argument "a" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at a.pl line 12.
```

We can see this caching with Devel::Peek. `pIOK` indicates an integer value is contained. (It's found in the `IV` slot.) `pNOK` indicates a floating point value is contained. (It's found in the `NV` slot.)

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -we'my $y = "a"; Dump( $y ); 0+$y; Dump( $y );'
SV = PV(0x56336a2a3ea0) at 0x56336a2d2d00
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
  PV = 0x56336a2db600 "a"\0
  CUR = 1
  LEN = 10
  COW_REFCNT = 1
Argument "a" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.
SV = PVNV(0x56336a2a2220) at 0x56336a2d2d00
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pIOK,pNOK,pPOK)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0x56336a2db600 "a"\0
  CUR = 1
  LEN = 10
  COW_REFCNT = 1
```